# FirefoxOS and Gecko SDK on Windows

Tags: windows, firefox-os, geckosdk

I am trying to get my hands dirty of firefox OS apps. I tried to follow instructions on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Gecko_SDK
to get the SDK. I downloaded Gecko 22.0 (Firefox 22.0) zip file for windows.
Could anyone please tell me how to build it on windows system. The details given on the website are not as clear as I expected(I had expected them to be like that on android's site). Or is there a binary available for the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No SDK needed, it is all HTML5. If people talk about SDKs in that context, its often frameworks or maybe tools that can export to HTML5. But generally, you can use all the languages that work in a browser and use them without any framework or SDK to make an app.

The developer docs on Marketplace have this great intro on app development and testing: https://marketplace.firefox.com/developers/docs/quick_start

Happy Hacking!

Answer (score 0):

The "SDK" you are looking for is probably the [Firefox OS Simulator Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/hu/firefox/addon/firefox-os-simulator/) for the Mozilla Firefox browser. Actually, all you need to test your applications for most hosted ones is a browser of some sort, but the Simulator (*also called as R2D2B2G*) lets you preview most of the phones' functionality, API-s and install packaged apps.

Besides installing and testing your applications you will also get a feel of *Gaia* - the user interface of Firefox OS, written, too, in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Like many of the answers here, there's no real SDK, as Firefox OS apps are basically HTML5 web pages with a **manifest.webapp** The firefox OS Simulator mentioned by Flaki is great to test your app.

I recommend watching this short video from Robert Nyman, one of Mozilla's FFos evangelists on getting started with it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqyrldlSx_o

And this is a good tutorial on developing an app: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/06/building-a-todo-app-for-firefox-os-part-1/